# Java certification sample

Tags: java

What is considered an object in this question?  There are 7 doubles in the array plus the array itself.

How many objects will be present after the following code fragment has executed?

```
double[] ann = new double[ 7 ];
double[] bob;
bob = ann;
```

2
7
14
1

Comment: I think if you used capital Double , it could be 7 separate objects. but here, as Nambari says, it's 1

Comment: @Adel Then there would be 8 objects as you have to count the array as well

Comment: @Robin - Aah yes, good point, thanks!!!

Answer (score 7):

only one object `new double[ 7 ];`

double[] bob; also references same object created in above step.

Answer (score 2):

There will only one object. The one you create with `new double[7]`. `bob` and `ann` are simply references to that object, and the 7 doubles are primitives.

Answer (score 2):

There is one object: the `double[7]`, with 2 references to it (`ann` and `bob`).
Since the array contains [primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), those are not `Object` instances so you do not need to count them

Answer (score 2):

`double[] ann = new double[ 7 ];`

You have create an `Array Object` which is now referred by an Array Object Reference Variable `ann`.

```
double[] bob;
bob = ann;
```

In the above line you are Creating an Array Object Reference Variable `bob`. And assigning the reference to the `Array Object` which is also referred by `ann`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I tested it with some code.

```
 public class TestCode {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double[] ann = new double[ 7 ];
            double[] bob;
            bob = ann;
            System.out.println(bob.getClass().getSimpleName());
            System.out.println(bob[6]);

            //there are 7 double references initialized to 0.0
        //array refs point to same object
        //1 object of type double[]
    }

}
```